# My Inputformat on hive cannot find when calling MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm using CDH cluster. 
After writing an Inputformat, I copied it to all HiveServer2 libs and re-start HiveServer2.
When I create a table using my inputformat and write a common query like 'select *', it can run and everything is right!
BUT!
When I write a query which should using MapReduce like `'where'` or `'join'` or `'count'`, it will throw a Class Not Found error:

> *Error: java.io.IOException: cannot find class
>   com.my.parquet.MyParquetInputFormat
>    at
>   
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:714)
>
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.(MapTask.java:169)
>
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
>
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>     at
>   
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
>
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)*
>
> Wish you helps!

Comment: Which client are you using (Hive CLI, beeline, ambari views etc)? Copied jar to all HiveServer2 libs does it mean on nodes where HiveServer2 runs ?

Comment: Hive Cli and beeline(hue) have the same problem.

Comment: Tell us more about the cluster, what you are trying to do, and what you did

Comment: I just want to write an inputformat to read some customized parquet files...

Comment: When I do a common query like select * from table, it runs with no error.

Comment: But when I query like 'join','where' which will use MapReduce&Yarn, it will throw no this inputformat class error

Comment: @OrisonChan Are you very sure that your jar file is error-free?

Comment: Yes. And I think class-not-found error is not related to errors in jar.